# Only include values from the latest timestamp into the query result

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, subquery

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e0209bc3f854fb9ece6223c839b5083f)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp TIMESTAMP,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    sales_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(time_stamp, product, sales_quantity)
VALUES 
("2020-01-14 07:15:30", "Product_A", "100"),
("2020-01-14 07:15:30", "Product_B", "300"),
("2020-01-14 07:18:45", "Product_A", "200"),
("2020-01-14 07:18:45", "Product_B", "900"),

("2020-01-15 07:19:23", "Product_A", "400"),
("2020-01-15 07:19:23", "Product_B", "270"),
("2020-01-15 07:45:10", "Product_A", "900"),
("2020-01-15 07:45:10", "Product_B", "340");
```

**Expected Restult:**

```
time_stamp             sales_quantity
2020-01-14              1.100
2020-01-15              1.240
```

---

As you can see in the table there are multiple `TIMESTAMP` per day. 
Now, I want to query the `sum` of the `sales_quantity` for each `TIMESTAMP` but only the **lates ones** should be **included**.

Therefore, in the example the `TIMESTAMP` with `07:15:30` and `07:19:23` should be ignored.

I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
MAX(time_stamp),
SUM(sales_quantity) AS sales_quantity
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, I get the error `Can't group on 'MAX(time_stamp)'`. 
How do I need to modify the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a condition with `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause so that you aggregate only the rows with the latest `time_stamp` of each day:

```
SELECT DATE(s.time_stamp) time_stamp,
       SUM(s.sales_quantity) sales_quantity
FROM sales s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sales WHERE DATE(time_stamp) = DATE(s.time_stamp) AND time_stamp > s.time_stamp)
GROUP BY DATE(s.time_stamp);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1bc0cb1bd720e658d2671571abe78eaf).

If you are using MySql 8.0+ and not MariaDB 10.3 (like your fiddle) then you could also do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       DATE(s.time_stamp) time_stamp,
       FIRST_VALUE(SUM(s.sales_quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(s.time_stamp) ORDER BY s.time_stamp DESC) sales_quantity
FROM sales s
GROUP BY s.time_stamp;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4beb522d563f306861740829c5346f7).

Results:

```
> time_stamp | sales_quantity
> :--------- | -------------:
> 2020-01-14 |           1100
> 2020-01-15 |           1240
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select date(time_stamp) date_stamp, sum(product) sales_quantity
from sales s
where s.time_stamp = (
    select max(s1.time_stamp) 
    from sales s1 
    where s1.time_stamp >= date(s.time_stamp) and s1.time_stamp < date(s.time_stamp) + interval 1 day
)
group by date_stamp
order by date_stamp
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use `rank()`:

```
select date(time_stamp) date_stamp, sum(product) sales_quantity
from (
    select s.*, rank() over(partition by date(time_stamp) order by time_stamp desc) rn
    from sales s
) t
where rn = 1
group by date_stamp
order by date_stamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` to rank the `time_stamp` values descending for each day (we use `DENSE_RANK` so that *all* the rows with the latest `time_stamp` get a row number of 1), and then `SUM` the quantities for those rows which have a rank of 1 (i.e. the latest value on the day):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT time_stamp,
         sales_quantity,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(time_stamp) ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) AS rn
  FROM sales
)
SELECT DATE(time_stamp) AS time_stamp,
       SUM(sales_quantity) AS sales_quantity
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY time_stamp
```

Output:

```
time_stamp  sales_quantity
2020-01-14  1100
2020-01-15  1240
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=eee5c000e906dd2f9b15383a7f86bd9e)

Answer (score 0):

try including the product on select list and group on it, example;

```
 SELECT
 product,
 MAX(time_stamp),
 SUM(sales_quantity) AS sales_quantity
 FROM sales
 GROUP BY product;
```

"group by 1" tries to group it according to your first column which was max(time_stamp)